# what does "mode" means in Mode-Stirred Reverberation Chamber?

Tags: electromagnetism

Recently I have been studying about properties of Mode-Stirred Reverberation Chamber (MSRC). I have run through some of the research papers about the MSRC, but none of them talks about the meaning of mode. What does the "mode" mean in the term MSRC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When pumping energy into a closed environment, you run the risk of creating standing waves.  These create a very inhomogeneous energy density inside the chamber, so you aren't really sure what your sample is seeing.  'Mode-stirrers' are meant to break up the standing waves and prevent their formation.  For radio/micro wave chambers they can be in the form of a "fan" - a rotating set of blades (hence the 'stirring' part of the name).  In your kitchen microwave that is too complicated so they make the dish rotate to even out the energy deposition per unit volume.

Comment: So if I say "modal density", does it mean that number of "mode-stirrers" in the closed environment?

Comment: @qsmy - no, the modal density is related to how closely spaced the modes (standing waves) of the chamber are.  The job of the stirrer is to get rid of the standing waves. Closely spaced modes would generally mean you excite more of the modes at once, reducing the need for mode stirring (since you are distributing the power across many spatial modes).